# Need ALTER TYPE query to update a existing field in existing object

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, alter

I have already created a `TYPE` object `Example1` using the following query

```
CREATE OR replace type example1 AS OBJECT (
   emp_name varchar2(32),
   emp_location varchar2(32)
);
```

Now I want to increase the  `emp_location`'s length to `varchar2(50)` from `varchar2(32)`

I have tried different `ALTER TYPE` command and it is not working.

Can someone provide the correct syntax to update the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `alter type <<type_name>> modify attribute` statement.

```
alter type example1 modify attribute emp_location varchar2(50);
```

[Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4002.htm#i2112566)